# hasOwnProperty -wont show property even if it has the property

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, hasownproperty

I am trying to understand why the result when I call the below function is "no" because the property c should exist. Does anyone know why? Thanks!!!

```
var letters = function() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 20;
  };

  letters.prototype = {
    c: 10
  };

  var letters = new letters();

function looping(obj){
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(this.c)) {
console.log("ua");
}
else {
    console.log("no");
}
}
```

looping(letters);

Answer (score 2):

It *doesn't* "have own property" `c` though. `c` is part of its prototype, so it's not an own property of the object you are testing.

At least, that's what the answer would be if you were calling `obj.hasOwnProperty('c')` as you probably intended. What you're actually calling is `obj.hasOwnProperty(window.c)`, which is `obj.hasOwnProperty(undefined)`, which is clearly `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to hasOwnProperty should be a string.

```
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("c") ? "UA" : "no")
```

Also the whole point of hasOwnProperty is to tes that the property /isn't/ obtained from the prototype, so the test should fail.

Comment: What I wanted to do is this:                function looping(obj){
 var properties=[];
     if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("c")) {
 properties.push(key);
    }

    return properties;

    }        //so only push it to the properties array if its not the c property-thus pushing ll properties BUT that particular property, thats what I tried testing with hasOwnProperty

Comment: sorry I missed to include the loop  // for (var key in obj)

Comment: Right, I guess you want something like `function (o) { return Object.keys(o).filter(function (k) { return !o.hasOwnProperty(k) }) }`. But some more context would be helpful.